# How to show error message on true false value in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am working on a module and want to throw an error message of 401 when the value is false. 
I am doing something like this.

```
if(!$data) {
     throw new \ErrorException('Error found');
}
```

any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the helper methods to throw exceptions and display error messages as a response. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-abort

The same result could be achieved with `abort_unless()`.

```
// If data evaluates to false.
abort_unless($data, 401, 'Error found');
```